# Why the output is 'No console' is to the following code in java?

Tags: java, netbeans

The following code is perfect code as I  have copied from doc.oracle site. It compiles without any error in netbeans, but out put is:

No console.
Java Result:1

What should I do to get the console working. Does it need any tweaking in netbeans setting?. I am confused although I have some experience in java programming in IDE netbeans. I am using latest versions of JDK and well as of Netbean.

public class RegexTestHarness {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        System.err.println("No console.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while (true) {

        Pattern pattern = 
        Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: "));

        Matcher matcher = 
        pattern.matcher(console.readLine("Enter input string to search: "));

        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            console.format("I found the text" +
                " \"%s\" starting at " +
                "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                matcher.group(),
                matcher.start(),
                matcher.end());
            found = true;
        }
        if(!found){
            console.format("No match found.%n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You probably need to open the console view.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I have got the real cause of problem and confusion is over. (Here I am too late, as a roadside accident kept me away from the computer.)

Answer (score 4):

> I am using latest versions of JDK and well as of Netbeans.

NetBeans uses its own console, so there is no System Console at all. Try running it on the terminal and it should work.

Comment: Many many thanks for a very clear idea about the console. I have followed the concept. I have been thankless for a long period, but I was not able to use the computer as I suffered severe eyesight problem due to a road side accident.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html):

> If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the `System.console()` method. If no console device is available then an invocation of that method will return `null`.

NetBeans has no `System.console()`.

Use `System.in` to read an `System.out` to write.

Comment: Thanks for making me a little bit more clear about the NetBeans for System.out. Now I shall not console from there where it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity

```
public class RegexTestHarness {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


    while (true) {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("\nEnter your regex:");

        Pattern pattern = 
        Pattern.compile(br.readLine());

        System.out.println("\nEnter input string to search:");
        Matcher matcher = 
        pattern.matcher(br.readLine());

        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.format("I found the text" +
                " \"%s\" starting at " +
                "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                matcher.group(),
                matcher.start(),
                matcher.end());
            found = true;
        }
        if(!found){
            System.out.println("No match found.");
        }
    }
}
}
```